# How do I map a function to each row in a tibble in R?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to map a function to each row in a tibble. Please see code below. My desired workflow is as follows -

1. Convert a list with sub lists to a tibble
2. Map each row the tibble to a function

My desired output should be a list with a tibble as output for each row mapped to the function. See full code below -

```
# Packages 
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

# Function i want to map
sample_func <- function(tib){
    
    a <- tib$name
    b <- tib$qty
    c <- tib$price
    d <- tib$add
    
    e <- b+c+d
    
    t <- tibble(e = c(e), stock = c(a))
    
    return(t)
    
}

# Define the list with multiple sublists
lst <- list(c( "CHR1", 15, 222.14, 6), c( "CHR2", 10, 119.20, 10))

# Convert each sublist to a tibble and bind the rows
tib <- bind_rows(lapply(lst, function(x) {
    tibble(name = x[1], qty = x[2] %>% as.numeric(), price = x[3] %>% as.numeric(), 
           add = x[4] %>% as.numeric())
}))

# Apply the function to each row in the tibble using map()
result <- tib %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(temp = map(list(name, qty, price, add), sample_func)) %>%
    unnest(temp)
```

My desired output should be -

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      e name 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  243. CHR1 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      e name 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  139. CHR2
```

However when the final rowwise mapping, I get the following error -

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `temp = map(list(name, qty, price, add), sample_func)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `tib$name`:
! $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Basically, the goal is to turn each row into a standalone dataframe, correct?

Comment: There is a `rowwise` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to change the inputs of the `sample_func` function to be the names of the columns instead of the tibble, then you can do this with `pmap()`:

```
# Function i want to map
sample_func <- function(name, qty, price, add){
  
  a <- name
  b <- qty
  c <- price
  d <- add
  
  e <- b+c+d
  
  t <- tibble(e = c(e), stock = c(a))
  
  return(t)
  
}

# Define the list with multiple sublists
lst <- list(c( "CHR1", 15, 222.14, 6), c( "CHR2", 10, 119.20, 10))

# Convert each sublist to a tibble and bind the rows
tib <- bind_rows(lapply(lst, function(x) {
  tibble(name = x[1], qty = x[2] %>% as.numeric(), price = x[3] %>% as.numeric(), 
         add = x[4] %>% as.numeric())
}))

# Apply the function to each row in the tibble using map()
pmap(tib, sample_func)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a tibble to the function you may pass columns of the tibble as vector.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sample_func <- function(name, qty, price, add){
    res <- tibble(e = qty + price + add, stock = name)
    return(res)
}
```

You may then use `pmap` -

```
out <- tib %>%
  mutate(res = pmap(list(name, qty, price, add), sample_func))

out

# A tibble: 2 × 5
#   name    qty price   add res             
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>          
#1 CHR1     15  222.     6 <tibble [1 × 2]>
#2 CHR2     10  119.    10 <tibble [1 × 2]>


out$res
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#      e stock
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1  243. CHR1 

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#      e stock
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1  139. CHR2
```

You may use `unnest` to get separate columns.

```
out %>% unnest(res)

#  name    qty price   add     e stock
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1 CHR1     15  222.     6  243. CHR1 
#2 CHR2     10  119.    10  139. CHR2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could just apply the `sample_func` on the `pick`ed dataset and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tib %>% 
  transmute(temp = sample_func(pick(everything()))) %>% 
  unnest(where(is_tibble))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      e stock
  <dbl> <chr>
1  243. CHR1 
2  139. CHR2
```

---

If we want it as a `list` of `tibble`s

```
tib %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   reframe(temp = list(sample_func(pick(everything())))) %>% 
   pull(temp)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      e stock
  <dbl> <chr>
1  243. CHR1 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      e stock
  <dbl> <chr>
1  139. CHR2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output and without changing your function or tibble we can use `dplyr::rowwise()` and `dplyr::group_map()`.

With `rowwise` we tell 'dplyr' to treat each row as a group. With `group_map` we apply a function to each group (in our case row) and the function takes the `data.frame` of each group as input  `.x` which fits your `sample_func()` perfectly.

```r
library(dplyr)

tib %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  group_map(~ sample_func(.x))

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>       e stock
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  243. CHR1 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>       e stock
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  139. CHR2
```

Data from OP

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Function i want to map
sample_func <- function(tib){
  
  a <- tib$name
  b <- tib$qty
  c <- tib$price
  d <- tib$add
  
  e <- b+c+d
  
  t <- tibble(e = c(e), stock = c(a))
  
  return(t)
  
}

# Define the list with multiple sublists
lst <- list(c( "CHR1", 15, 222.14, 6), c( "CHR2", 10, 119.20, 10))

# Convert each sublist to a tibble and bind the rows
tib <- bind_rows(lapply(lst, function(x) {
  tibble(name = x[1], qty = x[2] %>% as.numeric(), price = x[3] %>% as.numeric(), 
         add = x[4] %>% as.numeric())
}))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>